# MySql how to collaborate remotely ona project

Tags: mysql

Me and my friend have to do a project in Mysql and i am trying to find how me and my friend can work on mysql together from our own workstations. Is there a way where we both can work on the same database together without being physically present.
I am fairly new to mysql.

Comment: Yes, there is: use a database that both of you can access

Comment: Feel free to check https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take cheap shared hosting that has MySQL databases and preferably also PHPmyAdmin and cPanel or any other panel to easily manage your databases. In that way, you have minimum hassle to create and manage databases that you can both access.

Google "compare cheap shared hosting" and that's it. Or take this quick Google result I got: https://www.pcmag.com/picks/the-best-cheap-web-hosting-services

If you're not happy to pay $1-$2 per month for hosting then you can install WAMPP or XAMPP on Windows machine but then you'll have to also Google how to forward ports from your router.

Edited 3aug2020: For a free MySQL hosting for up to 5MB free storage please, check https://www.freemysqlhosting.net

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program like XAMPP to host mysql and port-forward phpmyadmin so your friend can visit your db

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

If you have MYSQL running on a server or your local computer you can both access phpmyadmin (http://server-ip/phpmyadmin) you can also use programs like Navicat (paid) or HeidiSQL (Free).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the database remotely accessible, in which case your friend can connect and work on it as well.

Without knowing more about your network setup it is difficult to say how you should proceed, but generally it is enough to spin up a mysql-server instance on the host machine, then forward a WAN port to the LAN address and port of the host machine.